# How to implement lookbehind and lookahead for lexing bold and italic text ranges in Markdown-like syntax?

Tags: antlr4, lookbehind, regex-lookarounds

I am building a parser for a Markdown-like syntax and am currently struggling to implement robust support for bold and italic text ranges. I would like to "translate" the following regular expression for the beginning of a bold range into the ANTLR4 lexer syntax (the expression is taken from the Markdown syntax highlighting for the Atom editor):

```
(?<=^|[^\w\d\*])\*\*(?!$|\*|\s)
```

The positive lookbehind checks if the "**" sequence is at the start of the string or not preceded by a word, a digit, or another asterisk. The negative lookahead checks that the sequence comes not before the end of the string and is not followed by another asterisk or any whitespace character.

I have already learned that I have to use semantic predicates in ANTLR4 to do a lookahead (using _input.LA(1)), doing something like this:

```
  ASTERISK_BOLD_START
      : { /*Lookbehind checks*/}? '**' {/*Lookahead checks with _input.LA(1)*/}?
      ;
```

But how do I implement the lookbehind checks? And how can I check for the beginning or end of the whole string parsed?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a regular expression to create parser grammar from. Both techniques work differently and you could easily move in a wrong direction. Your idea of doing a lot of look behind and look ahead is such a wrong direction. It's typical for (complex) regular expressions, but not normal parsers. Instead look at what other grammar authors have written. There's [one grammar here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497247/html-markdown-style-grammar-for-antlr4) and there's [Antmark over there at Github](https://github.com/mar9000/antmark). You could also start by taking an [EBNF for Markdown](https://github.com/Domysee/MarkdownEbnf/blob/master/Markdown%20EBNF.txt) and create your grammar from that.

However, be preprared for some trouble. Markdown is not a context free grammar and hence difficult to parse. The blog posting [Why isn't there a formal grammar for Markdown?](http://roopc.net/posts/2014/markdown-cfg/) explains some details.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I already knew these two implementations. The one on Stackoverflow ignores Markdown within italic ranges (and it does not implement bold ranges at all). The one on Github is called by its author "unusable" and "ugly". It does all the context sensitive stuff in the parser which makes the parser slow and complicated. 

I think because of the context sensitivity there really is no way around using semantic predicates. This may not be the most elegant way, but I think it is suited well for a loose Markdown-like syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find one-character lookahead useful in lexer in some circumstances. What I use it for is to match numbers - now you can write numbers as digits or digits with a separator in groups of three, e.g. `100,000,000`.

This is the lookahead implementation in the grammar file:

```
@lexer::members {
    //implements one character look ahead
    public boolean charLA(String strPattern) {
        String nextCharacter = _input.getText(new Interval(getCharIndex(), getCharIndex()+1));
        java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(strPattern,java.util.regex.Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
        return (nextCharacter != null && !nextCharacter.isEmpty() && pattern.matcher(nextCharacter).find());
    }  
}
```

These are the grammar rules matching the numbers:

`INTEGER_GROUPED : ([0-9])?([0-9])?[0-9] ((' '|',') [0-9][0-9][0-9])+ {!charLA("[0-9]")}?;`

`INTEGER : [0-9]+ ;`

This assures that when the user writes 1,000 - it will be matched by `INTEGER_GROUPED` but when the user writes 1,1234 it will be actually matched by two `INTEGER`s 1 and 1234. Without the lookahead, it would be matched as `INTEGER_GROUPED` `1,123` and `INTEGER` `4`.

Not saying this is the only way how to do this but I find it quite useful.

Comment: And `_tokenStartCharIndex` lexer variable could be used to implement lookbehind.